# WordPress taxonomy.php not working for custom taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

I have a custom post type "certificates" & I have a custom taxonomy "certificate_category" that registered for "certificates" custom post type. here is my definition of taxonomy:

```
$args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' =>array( 'slug' => 'topics' )
    );
        register_taxonomy('certificate_category', 'certificates', $args);
```

This taxonomy has two terms with names "international" & "interior". I have created taxonomy.php for display "certificate_category" taxonomy (international & interior have same template).

The url for "internatonal" term is  mysit/topics/international & for "interior" term is mysit.com/topics/interior and they both redirect to index.php.

What should I do to show taxonomy.php ?

Comment: Is the taxonomy registration code in the init hook?
Have you visited the Settings/Permalinks section after you added the registration code in your functions.php?
You can try disabling plugins / switching your theme just for troubleshooting.

Comment: Yes it has a hook. What should I do with settings/permalinks?

Comment: Just open Settings/Permalinks url, and then try opening the taxonomy term url.

Comment: My problem is I have another custom post type and and another taxonomy  that they work correctly with taxonomy.php , but taxonomy.php doesn't work for "certificate_category" taxonomy. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Have you visited the Settings/Permalinks?
I have created a site with your taxonomy registration code and it worked just fine with my taxonomy.php.

Comment: create taxonomy-certificate.php

Comment: what should I do in Settings/permalinks? which items should I select?

Comment: Just opening the Settings/Permalinks section in wp-admin refreshes the rewrite rules, and maybe that was the problem, since your taxonomy registration code was added after the last time you visited the permalinks section.

Comment: I just write in category and tags box ,topics it works , thanks, but I don't know it reads from which file , I have taxonomy.php and archive.php but none of them is showing. where is problem?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to change any settings in the permalinks section, just visit it, then try opening /topics/international. The template you need is just taxonomy.php.
I created a site with such configuration, and it worked on 1st try.
Do you have any posts in any of the taxonomy terms?

Comment: How should I open /topics/international.?

Comment: How should I open /topics/international.?I have 2 posts in international and 4 posts in interior.

Comment: it redirects to index.php

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your Settings/Permalinks?

Comment: can you give me your email address?

Comment: Can you share a onedrive or dropbox url?